# Regex get all numbers in a string into one group

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have a column defined as a string with numbers in it
I want to extract just the numbers into one single group however, I am able to get only the groups of consecutive numbers by `(\d+)`

e.g.
`sale34sfo56rce22` to be extracted to `salesforce` and `345622`
But I get groups of `34 56 22`

`Pow21er56BI` to be extracted to `PowerBI` and `2156`

`Na12me` to be extracted to `Name` and `12`

What should be the best way?

I am using Tableau hence, I cannot extract each group and concat them as Tableau just extracts the first group and not the next.

Comment: Can't you use regexreplace to get rid of all digits or get rid of all non-digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variables in JS to have it.

```
var target = "12div3_id_12";
var tar_str = target.replace(/[0-9.]/g, "");
var tar_num = target.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");

console.log(tar_str)
console.log(tar_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution without joining an array to a string is @JvdV's suggestion.

```
import re

re.sub(r"[a-z]", "", "sale34sfo56rce22")  # 345622
re.sub(r"\d", "", "sale34sfo56rce22")     # salesforce
```

Or just you can filter chars from the string and join them together

```
"".join(filter(str.isdigit, "sale34sfo56rce22"))  # 345622
"".join(filter(str.isalpha, "sale34sfo56rce22"))  # salesforce
```